# Buildozer doing unnecessary downloads

Tags: kivy, buildozer

This problem occurs every time I execute:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

to test my app on an android device.

Each and every time, buildozer re-downloads

> Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1

I assume that this is completely unnecessary and would really like to stop it from happening, as it would save a lot of time. How might I stop it?

Here is the **buildozer.spec**:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application title = My App

# (str) Package name package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging) package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files) source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2) version = 1.0

# (list) Application requirements requirements = kivy, plyer

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all) orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not fullscreen = 1


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =
```

Comment: When did you install buildozer? Is it the most recent version?

Comment: @inclement it's version 0.16-dev ... from 'buildozer version'

Comment: @inclement I have updated buildozer with pip. Will check to see if that's worked

Comment: @inclement that seems to have done the trick alright!Please provide this as the official Answer if you wish.

Comment: I don't think editing the title with "answered in comments" is a good idea. If inclement didn't want to post it as an answer, you should (maybe as a community answer or maybe not).

Comment: @Fermiparadox Fair point